# How to get text from dynamically created TextView in android?

Tags: android, textview

```
private void textview(String question) {
    TextView clientAddress = new TextView(this);
    clientName.setGravity(1);
    clientAddress.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(1));
    clientAddress.setText(question);
    clientAddress.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    linearLayout.addView(clientAddress);
    clientAddress.setTextSize(20);
    clientAddress.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    clientAddress.setPadding(7, 10, 0, 10);
}
```

I am calling this function to create 6 TextViews dynamically. but i am confused , how to get text from these TextViews. can anyone suggest me the solution?

Comment: so you want to get text of a `TextView`? whats the problem with the getter?

Comment: i am new to android, can you please describe it little bit?

Comment: just use `clientAddress.getText()`

Comment: Dear, my 6 textviews are getting same object name i.e. clientAddress . So how can i get text from this line?

Comment: Can you show more code where you add this textview to Orignal View 
View.addView()   method

Comment: linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_form);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);



linearLayout.addView(clientAddress);

Answer (score 0):

you can use the gettext() method to get the text from the text view. and if you wants to convert the fetched text into string then you can use tostring() .

```
String fetchedtext = clientAddress.getText().toString();
```

Comment: my 6 textviews are getting same object name i.e. clientAddress . So how can i get text from this line?

Comment: Please do not post bare code also include an explanation of what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a different object for each and every `TextView`. and after using those object you can get values of `TextView`. using `getText()` property of `TextView`.

You can also create array of `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
private void textview(int position, String question) {
        TextView clientAddress = new TextView(this);
        clientName.setGravity(1);
        clientAddress.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(1));
        clientAddress.setText(question);
        clientAddress.setTag(position);
        clientAddress.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        linearLayout.addView(clientAddress);
        clientAddress.setTextSize(20);
        clientAddress.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        clientAddress.setPadding(7, 10, 0, 10);
    }

  public String getTextFromTextView(int positionOfTextView , LinearLayout mLinearLayout){
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <((ViewGroup)mLinearLayout).getChildCount() ; i++) {
        if(((ViewGroup) mLinearLayout).getChildAt(i)!=null ){
            View mView =((ViewGroup) mLinearLayout).getChildAt(i);
            if(mView instanceof  TextView){
                TextView mTextView = (TextView)mView;
                if(mTextView!=null && mTextView.getTag()!=null && positionOfTextView==(int) mTextView.getTag() ){
                    result =mTextView.getText().toString();
                }
            }else {
                TextView mTextView =  (TextView) mView.findViewWithTag(positionOfTextView);
                if(mTextView!=null){
                    result =mTextView.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```