# How to get text from TextViews which are created dynamically in android?

Tags: android, firebase, textview, dynamically-generated

I do not know the number. of textview which should be created at runtime. List of Textviews are getting from server. I am creating textviews using below function. Since i am new to android i unable to get text from all textviews. Please suggest me the solution

private void textview(String text)
 {

```
    TextView txt_view= new TextView(this);


    txt_view.setText(text);

    linearLayout.addView(txt_view);

}
```

Please suggest me the solution i m stuck in getting the text from many textview

[image]

Above image is my form, what i want to get text from all views which are created dynamically and store to firebase

Comment: txt_view.getText().tostring();  
This will help you.

Comment: it will give the text of single text view but if m having n number of text views with same object name how can i get text fromm all these n no. of text views

Comment: This question didn't go over so well an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828261/how-to-get-text-from-dynamically-created-textview-in-android

Comment: Use Arraylist with Modal class. Set the values of textview with perticular modal class and get the data from the modal whenever you need it. @ĜüptåŠhãsĥwæt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add your `TextView` to `HashMap` with a `unique key`
and match your key and get value from `map`, it will surely help you. after that at time of fetching data use for loop and get data using that `unique key`

Comment: Yeah!! Might be HashMap can work for me. Will you please add the basic code so I can implement in my code

Comment: private void textview(String key, String quest) {  
      tv_custom = new TextView(this);    
    tv_custom.setText(quest);      
  linearLayout.addView(tv_custom);        map.put(key, quest);    }

Comment: Map <String, TextView> map;
map = new Map <String, TextView>   HashMap();

private void textview(String key, String value) {  

      tv_custom = new TextView(this);    
    tv_custom.setText(value);      
  linearLayout.addView(tv_custom);    
    map.put(key, quest);   
 }

now your value added to map with a unique key, and get using following:

for (Map<String, TextView>.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {       
             String key = entry.getKey();      
              EditText value=entry.getValue();       
             String text=value.getText().toString();
}

Comment: declare TextView tv_custom; globally

Answer (score 1):

Just get it from your `TextView` object, like this:

```
txt_view.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use same object of TextView to gt text of it. txt_view.[getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()).toString();

You can get same TextView object by finding childs of LinearLayout.

Comment: can you please elaborate how can i find the child of Linear Layout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615723/getting-child-elements-from-linearlayout

Comment: @ĜüptåŠhãsĥwæt is this helpful?

Comment: yes it works for me for getting text from textview Thanks 
but what i really want is i want text from textview and from the corresponding edittext to push the value to firebase

Answer (score -1):

How about to store them in an ArrayList and iterate over it to get all and maniupulate them afterwards.

```
ArrayList<TextView> alTextViews = new ArrayList<>();

private void textview(String text) {

    TextView txt_view= new TextView(this);
    alTextView.add(txt_view);


    txt_view.setText(text);

    linearLayout.addView(txt_view);

}
```

with

```
alTextView.get(0).getText().toString();
```

you'll get the text

Comment: what will be get(0) provide me here. if position , then it will not give the desired output because i did not know the number of text views in my layout so how can i get the text from last textview.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i<alTextView.size(); i++) { String text = alTextView.get(i).getText().toString();} to get one after another

or even better with an iterator:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24943728/7325737

the last one: alTextView.get(alTextView.size()-1).getText().toString();